# How to extract author emails from Github Repository

Tags: java, spring, request, github-api

I want to receive a list with all the authors that have had contribution to a github repository, and i tried with sourcetree but i didn't find a way. This is a project that i must use spring framework

Answer (score 3):

As you're using Java it may not be a bad idea to use a wrapper for the GitHub API which will simplify things for you, take a look [here](https://developer.github.com/libraries/) for some Java libraries you can use.

Using [com.jcabi.github](http://github.jcabi.com/) library you can do something like:

```
import com.jcabi.github.RtGithub;
import com.jcabi.github.Issue;
import com.jcabi.github.Github;
import com.jcabi.github.Repo;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Github github = new RtGithub(".. your OAuth token ..");
    Repo repo = github.repos().get(new Coordinates.Simple("jcabi", "jcabi-github"));
    System.out.println(repo.collaborators()); // Get's all collaborators for the specified repo
    // you can also iterate this:
    Iterator iter = repo.collaborators.iterate().iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext())
        System.out.println(iter.next().login()) // gets username
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hm, perhaps. It's quite a heavy-handed approach to pull in a whole library for what is basically a simple HTTP request though.

Comment: @Michael Maybe, but OP hasn't really described their needs so it could be the case that OP wants more than just small details about a repository. I personally don't mind using libraries in such cases as if my requirements change, I don't need to worry too much about using a library later.

Comment: Hey, i had an error at repo.collaborators.iterate() , i don't know exactly why because i imported the jar from the github. Please if anyone can show me exactly how to do it

Comment: @Michael i am a beginner in Maven and Spring , and really i don't know exactly how this works, but for me has an error at  repo.collaborators.iterate(), even though i imported the jar from the github api, if you had time can you show me an extended version,

Comment: @duricuvlad I've made an edit to the code, could you try now? I've not used this library before so I'm not sure what results you may be getting.

Answer (score 2):

[This page of the documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/) suggests you should be able to submit a HTTP request to the following URL:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/collaborators
```

replacing `{owner}` and `{repo}` with the relevant names.

This should return a list of all collaborators in JSON format.

Comment: I've edited your answer quite significantly to give you an example of what I would expect an okay answer to look like. You don't need to bother with prefixing your edit with "EDIT:" in future.